# require a js method for Nuxt page methods

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt js. Is there a way to separate code from a method that will be re used in many other requests methods and place it in another folder/location maybe call it devour.js

```
async asyncData({ $axios, route, params, $auth }) {
    const jsonApi = new JsonApi({ apiUrl: $axios.defaults.baseURL });
    jsonApi.headers["Authorization"] = $auth.getToken("local");
    // this code below defining models i call it in many other pages many times //
    jsonApi.define("team", {
      name: "",
      abbreviation: "",
      sport: {
        jsonApi: "hasOne",
        type: "sports"
      }
    });
    jsonApi.define("sport", {
      name: "",
      teams: {
        jsonApi: "hasMany",
        type: "teams"
      },
      tournaments: {
        jsonApi: "hasMany",
        type: "tournaments"
      }
    });
    // up to here //
    let { data, errors, meta, links } = await jsonApi.find(
      "team",
      route.params.id,
      {
        include: "sport"
      }
    );
    return { data };
  },
```

So I'm thinking of placing that code I mentioned in another page.

UPDATE:

I tried doing this like David said in the comments but when I import it just wont work. It says it is undefined.

This is my devour file

```
import JsonApi from 'devour-client';

export default function ({ $axios, $auth }) {
  const jsonApi = new JsonApi({ apiUrl: $axios.defaults.baseURL });
  jsonApi.headers['Authorization'] = $auth.getToken('local');
  jsonApi.define('team', {
    name: '',
    abbreviation: '',
    sport: {
      jsonApi: 'hasOne',
      type: 'sports'
    }
  });
  jsonApi.define('sport', {
    name: '',
    teams: {
      jsonApi: 'hasMany',
      type: 'teams'
    },
    tournaments: {
      jsonApi: 'hasMany',
      type: 'tournaments'
    }
  });
  return jsonApi
}
```

And this is my current script where I use this

```
import jsonApi from '~/api/devour';
```

```
async asyncData({ $axios, $auth, jsonApi }) {
    let { data, errors, meta, links } = await jsonApi.findAll('teams', {
      include: 'sport'
    });
    return { data };
  },
```

Comment: `console.log(jsonApi)` is `undefined`?

Comment: yes its undefined :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to store common component methods in #NUXT.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088798/where-to-store-common-component-methods-in-nuxt-js)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

**lib/api.js**

```js
const loadStuff = async (params) => {...};
export { loadStuff };
```

**components/widget.vue**

```js
import { loadStuff } from '~/lib/api';
```

Note that the `~/lib/api` path will vary depending on the file name and your build environment. E.g. it could be `@/lib/api`.